# ServiceStack Redis Client Expecting Older version of ServiceStack.Common

Tags: redis, nuget-package, servicestack

I just NuGetted ServiceStack.Redis 3.1.3 but as its dependencies it also gets ServiceStack.Common and ServiceStack.Text 3.1.6

Now when I build the application everything is OK.

But, when I run the application some of the Redis Client methods execute properly but some of them e.g. (RedisClient.GetAllKeys) gives throws the exception

`Could not load file or assembly 'ServiceStack.Common, Version=1.0.4336.27526, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.`

Then i removed all the dll's and nuget packgage config, and explicitly did a NuGet ServiceStack.Common -Version 3.1.3 and got it. But then when i tried to NuGet ServiceStack.Redis -Version 3.1.3 it automatically removed the 3.1.3 version of Common and downloaded the 3.1.6 version !!!

Arrrghhh, I hate over intelligent installers.

How do I fix this ?

Does the publisher of ServiceStack even know about this issue ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok ! Found the Issue.

I was trying to use ServiceStack from a console application and it was configured to build in "ClientProfile" mode.

ServiceStack internally references System.Web which wasn't being accessible at runtime.

I switched the Application to Build using the full framework mode and everything works ok now.

Thanks anyways mythz !

Answer (score 0):

Nope, ServiceStack was not aware of this issue. Though we'd like to know what's causing it.

I've tried a fresh install of ServiceStack.Redis and it works as expected.

To remove your dlls you need to go into NuGet package manager and finding the installed ServiceStack.Redis Package and clicking un-install. This should ensure the next install of the Project downloads it from the NuGet website and doesn't re-use your dirty dll cache.

Failing that ensure you have the latest version of NuGet and that your old NuGet caches are cleared. i.e. find and delete the NuGet /packages folder.